# Numpy - how to convert an array of vector indices to a mask?

Tags: python, numpy

Given a `np.ndarray` named `indices` with a `n` rows and variable length vector in each row I want to create a boolean mask of `n` rows and `m` rows where `m` is a pre-known value equal to the greatest value possible in `indices`.
Take note that the indices specified in `indices` refer to per-row indices, and not global matrix indices.

For example, given:

```py
indices = np.array([
    [2, 0],
    [0],
    [4, 7, 1]
])

# Expected output
print(mask)
[[ True False  True False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False False False False]
 [False  True False False  True False False  True]]
```

`m` is known beforehand (the maximum length of each row in `mask`) and doesn't need to be inferred from `indices`

**Notice**: This is different from converting an array of indices to a mask where the indices refer to the resulting matrix indices

Comment: Could you clarify your last sentence a little better? To me it looks like what your expected output is all about.

Comment: If you have two vectors you can just create a zeros vector of the maximum size, and use indexing to do something like `mask[indices] = True`, but you can't do that in this case since the indices refer to in-row indices, and not matrix indices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no direct way of doing this in a fully vectorized way, for larger inputs, a single application of `mask[full_row_indices, full_col_indices]` with the pre-computed full list of indices is faster than multiple applications of `mask[partial_row_indices, partial_col_indices]`.
Memory-wise, the multiple applications are also less demanding because no intermediate `full_row_indices`/`full_col_indices` need to be built.
Of course this would generally depend on the length of `indices`.

Just to get some feeling on how much faster the different possible solutions could, the following functions have been tested:

```py
import numpy as np
import random


def gen_mask_direct(col_indices, cols=None):
    if cols is None:
        cols = np.max(np.concatenate(col_indices)) + 1
    rows = len(col_indices)
    mask = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=bool)
    for row_index, col_index in enumerate(col_indices):
        mask[row_index, col_index] = True
    return mask 


def gen_mask_loops(col_indices, cols=None):
    rows = len(col_indices)
    row_indices = tuple(i for i, j in enumerate(col_indices) for _ in j)
    col_indices = tuple(sum(col_indices, ()))
    if cols is None:
        cols = np.max(col_indices) + 1
    mask = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=bool)
    mask[row_indices, col_indices] = True
    return mask


def gen_mask_np_repeat(col_indices, cols=None):
    rows = len(col_indices)
    lengths = list(map(len, col_indices))
    row_indices = np.repeat(np.arange(rows), lengths)
    col_indices = np.concatenate(col_indices)
    if cols is None:
        cols = np.max(col_indices) + 1
    mask = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=bool)
    mask[row_indices, col_indices] = True
    return mask


def gen_mask_np_concatenate(col_indices, cols=None):
    rows = len(col_indices)
    row_indices = tuple(np.full(len(col_index), i) for i, col_index in enumerate(col_indices))
    row_indices = np.concatenate(row_indices)
    col_indices = np.concatenate(col_indices)
    if cols is None:
        cols = np.max(col_indices) + 1
    mask = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=bool)
    mask[row_indices, col_indices] = True
    return mask
```

`gen_mask_direct()` is basically [@Derlin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57552953/5218354) and implements multiple applications of `mask[partial_row_indices, partial_col_indices]`.
All the others implement a single application of `mask[full_row_indices, full_col_indices]` with different ways of preparing the `full_row_indices` and the `full_col_indices`:

- `gen_mask_loops()` uses direct looping
- `gen_mask_np_repeat()` uses `np.repeat()` (and it is substantially the same as [@Divakar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57552904/5218354)
- `gen_mask_np_concatenate()` uses a combination of `np.full()` and `np.concatenate()`

---

A quick sanity check indicates that all these are equivalent:

```py
funcs = gen_mask_direct, gen_mask_loops, gen_mask_np_repeat, gen_mask_np_concatenate

random.seed(0)
test_inputs = [
    (tuple(
        tuple(sorted(set([random.randint(0, n - 1) for _ in range(random.randint(1, n - 1))])))
                for _ in range(random.randint(1, n - 1))))
    for n in range(5, 6)
    ]
print(test_inputs)
# [((0, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4), (1, 4), (0, 1, 4))]

for func in funcs:
    print('Func:', func.__name__)
    for test_input in test_inputs:    
        print(func(test_input).astype(int))
```

```
Func: gen_mask_direct
[[1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 1]]
Func: gen_mask_loops
[[1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 1]]
Func: gen_mask_np_repeat
[[1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 1]]
Func: gen_mask_np_concatenate
[[1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 1]]
```

---

Here are some benchmarks (using the code from [here](https://github.com/norok2/BenchmarkTemplateIPY)):

[image: benchmark_full]

and zooming to the fastest:

[image: benchmark_zoom]

supporting the overall statement that, typically, a single application of `mask[...]` for full indices is faster multiple applications of `mask[...]` for partial indices.

---

For completeness, the following code was used to generate the inputs, compare the outputs, run the benchmarks and prepare the plots:

```py
def gen_input(n):
    random.seed(0)
    return tuple(
        tuple(sorted(set([random.randint(0, n - 1) for _ in range(random.randint(n // 2, n - 1))])))
        for _ in range(random.randint(n // 2, n - 1)))


def equal_output(a, b):
    return np.all(a == b)


input_sizes = tuple(int(2 ** (2 + (3 * i) / 4)) for i in range(13))
print('Input Sizes:\n', input_sizes, '\n')


runtimes, input_sizes, labels, results = benchmark(
    funcs, gen_input=gen_input, equal_output=equal_output,
    input_sizes=input_sizes)


plot_benchmarks(runtimes, input_sizes, labels, units='ms')
plot_benchmarks(runtimes, input_sizes, labels, units='ms', zoom_fastest=2)
```

Comment: I checked with this dummy data `indices = np.array([list(np.random.randint(per_row, size=i)) for i in np.random.binomial(n=per_row, p=0.5, size=rows)])`, and depending on the  ratio of `rows` and `per_row`, one was faster than the other, but the difference was always with 100%, so no orders of magnitude

Comment: Surely enough. Perhaps I did not express myself clear enough. In both approaches there are *slower* loop pathways (not necessarily orders of magnitude) and for a certain combination of sizes (your `rows` and `per_row`) you will get different results. If `rows << per_row` partial masking is faster, if `rows >> per_row` partial masking is slower. If `rows ~ per_row` as what OP seemed to indicate, then one could *typically* expect partial masking to be ~2x slower, which is no order of magnitude, but could be significant. Memory-wise, partial application is always better.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way -

```
def mask_from_indices(indices, ncols=None):
    # Extract column indices
    col_idx = np.concatenate(indices)

    # If number of cols is not given, infer it based on max column index
    if ncols is None:
        ncols = col_idx.max()+1

    # Length of indices, to be used as no. of rows in o/p
    n = len(indices)

    # Initialize o/p array
    out = np.zeros((n,ncols), dtype=bool)

    # Lengths of each index element that represents each group of col indices
    lens = np.array(list(map(len,indices)))

    # Use np.repeat to generate all row indices
    row_idx = np.repeat(np.arange(len(lens)),lens)

    # Finally use row, col indices to set True values
    out[row_idx,col_idx] = 1
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [89]: mask_from_indices(indices)
Out[89]: 
array([[ True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True]])
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little about what each step in `mask_from_indices` does?

Comment: @bluesummers Added comments.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variant:

```
def create_mask(indices, m):
    mask = np.zeros((len(indices), m), dtype=bool)
    for i, idx in enumerate(indices):
        mask[i, idx] = True
    return mask
```

Usage:

```
>>> create_mask(indices, 8)
array([[ True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True]])
```

Comment: I like this code for clarity, but speedwise this can be substantially slower than a fully vectorized approach as soon as `len(indices)` increases.

Comment: @norok2 since `indices` is an array of dtype `object`, I don't see how you could easily vectorize this. At least it is just dependent on the number of rows, not the number of elements.

Comment: @MaartenFabré basically this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57552904/5218354

Comment: `lens = np.array(list(map(len,indices)))` also iterates over the `indices`, so I doubt this will make much of a difference. Making the array from the original `indices` is so convoluted, and I doubt will gain you a lot of speed, that I prefer the clarity of this solution over @Divakar's

Comment: @MaartenFabré I like doubting, but I prefer [measuring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57558095/5218354) :-)